# nunit command in bash do not accept static command?

Tags: nunit

I have a Program.dll which I execute with Nunit GUI Runner on windows 7. Works perfect. The `[Test]` method is static.

When I execute it through bash in linux, in the XML it says :

```
signature is not correct: it must be an instance method.
```

here is the method declaration

```
    [Test]
    static public void NUnitWriter()
```

why does it work in windows with the Nunit GUI runner but not with it's linux console counterpart?

Comment: Do you really mean [bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29), as in the *nix shell, or are you referring to [cmd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe), Windows' command prompt?  And by "NUnit program on Windows 7", you're referring to the NUnit GUI runner, correct?

Comment: added it to the question : Nunit GUI runner (didn't know the name before)
and bash as in linux bash
I guess maybe the console Nunit could be updated? If it is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible you're using an older version of the console application; [static test methods weren't supported until version 2.5](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=test&r=2.5).  You can check the version by running

```
> nunit-console.exe /?
NUnit-Console version 2.6.4.14350
Copyright (C) 2002-2012 Charlie Poole.
Copyright (C) 2002-2004 James W. Newkirk, Michael C. Two, Alexei A. Vorontsov.
Copyright (C) 2000-2002 Philip Craig.
All Rights Reserved.
...
```

If it's 2.4 or earlier, that's your problem.